# Unable to access python packages installed in Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy a pre-trained ML model (saved as .h5 file) to Azure ML. I have created an AKS cluster and trying to deploy the model as shown below:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import Model

from azureml.core.environment import Environment
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig

from azureml.core.webservice import AksWebservice, LocalWebservice
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget

workspace = Workspace.from_config(path="config.json")

env = Environment.get(workspace, name='AzureML-TensorFlow-1.13-GPU')

# Installing packages present in my requirements file
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    dependencies = f.readlines()
dependencies = [x.strip() for x in dependencies if '# ' not in x]
dependencies.append("azureml-defaults>=1.0.45")

env.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=dependencies)

# Including the source folder so that all helper scripts are included in my deployment
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='app.py', environment=env, source_directory='./ProcessImage')

aks_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=workspace, name='sketch-ppt-vm')

# Deployment with suitable config
deployment_config = AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=4, memory_gb=32)
model = Model(workspace, 'sketch-inference')
service = Model.deploy(workspace, "process-sketch-dev", [model], inference_config, deployment_config, deployment_target=aks_target, overwrite=True)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
print(service.state)
```

My main entry script requires some additional helper scripts, which I include by mentioning the source folder in my inference config.

I was expecting that the helper scripts I add should be able to access the packages installed while setting up the environment during deployment, but I get ModuleNotFoundError.

Here is the error output, along with the a couple of environment variables I printed while executing entry script:

```
    AZUREML_MODEL_DIR ----  azureml-models/sketch-inference/1
    PYTHONPATH ----  /azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/var/azureml-server:
    PATH ----  /azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/bin:/opt/miniconda/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/mpi/bin64
    Exception in worker process
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
        worker.init_process()
    File "/azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
        self.load_wsgi()
    File "/azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
        self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    File "/azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
        self.callable = self.load()
    File "/azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
        return self.load_wsgiapp()
    File "/azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
        return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
    File "/azureml-envs/azureml_6dc005c11e151f8d9427c0c6091a1bb9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
        __import__(module)
    File "/var/azureml-server/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
        import create_app
    File "/var/azureml-server/create_app.py", line 3, in <module>
        from app import main
    File "/var/azureml-server/app.py", line 32, in <module>
        from aml_blueprint import AMLBlueprint
    File "/var/azureml-server/aml_blueprint.py", line 25, in <module>
        import main
    File "/var/azureml-app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
        driver_module_spec.loader.exec_module(driver_module)
    File "/structure/azureml-app/ProcessImage/app.py", line 16, in <module>
        from ProcessImage.samples.coco.inference import run as infer
    File "/var/azureml-app/ProcessImage/samples/coco/inference.py", line 1, in <module>
        import skimage.io
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
```

The existing answers related to this aren't of much help. I believe there must be a simpler way to fix this, since AzureML specifically provides the feature to setup environment with pip/conda packages installed either by supplying requirements.txt file or individually.

What am I missing here? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some trial and error, creating a fresh environment and then adding the packages solved the problem for me. I am still not clear on why this didn't work when I tried to use [Environment.from_pip_requirements()](http://from%20azureml.core%20import%20Workspace%20from%20azureml.core.model%20import%20Model%20from%20azureml.core.environment%20import%20Environment,%20DEFAULT_GPU_IMAGE%20from%20azureml.core.conda_dependencies%20import%20CondaDependencies%20from%20azureml.core.model%20import%20InferenceConfig%20from%20azureml.core.webservice%20import%20AksWebservice,%20LocalWebservice%20from%20azureml.core.compute%20import%20ComputeTarget%20%20%20#%201.%20Instantiate%20the%20workspace%20workspace%20=%20Workspace.from_config(path=%22config.json%22)%20%20#%202.%20Setup%20the%20environment%20env%20=%20Environment(%27sketchenv%27)%20with%20open(%27requirements.txt%27)%20as%20f:%20#%20Fetch%20all%20dependencies%20as%20a%20list%20%20%20%20%20dependencies%20=%20f.readlines()%20dependencies%20=%20%5Bx.strip()%20for%20x%20in%20dependencies%20if%20%27#%20%27%20not%20in%20x%5D%20env.docker.base_image%20=%20DEFAULT_GPU_IMAGE%20env.python.conda_dependencies%20=%20CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=%5B%27numpy==1.17.4%27,%20%27Cython%27%5D,%20pip_packages=dependencies)%20%20#%203.%20Inference%20Config%20inference_config%20=%20InferenceConfig(entry_script=%27app.py%27,%20environment=env,%20source_directory=%27./ProcessImage%27)%20%20#%204.%20Compute%20target%20(using%20existing%20cluster%20from%20the%20workspacke)%20aks_target%20=%20ComputeTarget(workspace=workspace,%20name=%27sketch-ppt-vm%27)%20%20#%205.%20Deployment%20config%20deployment_config%20=%20AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=6,%20memory_gb=100)%20%20#%206.%20Model%20deployment%20model%20=%20Model(workspace,%20%27sketch-inference%27)%20#%20Registered%20model%20(which%20contains%20model%20files/folders)%20service%20=%20Model.deploy(workspace,%20%22process-sketch-dev%22,%20%5Bmodel%5D,%20inference_config,%20deployment_config,%20deployment_target=aks_target,%20overwrite=True)%20service.wait_for_deployment(show_output%20=%20True)%20print(service.state)). A detailed answer in this regard would be interesting to read.

My primary task was inference - object detection given an image, and we have our own model developed by our team. There are two types of imports I wanted to have:

**1. Standard python packages (installed through pip)**
This was solved by creating conda dependencies and add it to env object (Step 2)

**2. Methods/vars from helper scripts** (if you have pre/post processing to be done during model inference):
This was done by mentioning `source_directory` in InferenceConfig (step 3)

Here is my updated script which combines Environment creation, Inference and Deployment configs and using existing compute in the workspace (created through portal).

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core.environment import Environment, DEFAULT_GPU_IMAGE
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
from azureml.core.webservice import AksWebservice, LocalWebservice
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget


# 1. Instantiate the workspace
workspace = Workspace.from_config(path="config.json")

# 2. Setup the environment
env = Environment('sketchenv')
with open('requirements.txt') as f: # Fetch all dependencies as a list
    dependencies = f.readlines()
dependencies = [x.strip() for x in dependencies if '# ' not in x]
env.docker.base_image = DEFAULT_GPU_IMAGE
env.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=['numpy==1.17.4', 'Cython'], pip_packages=dependencies)

# 3. Inference Config
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='app.py', environment=env, source_directory='./ProcessImage')

# 4. Compute target (using existing cluster from the workspacke)
aks_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=workspace, name='sketch-ppt-vm')

# 5. Deployment config
deployment_config = AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=6, memory_gb=100)

# 6. Model deployment
model = Model(workspace, 'sketch-inference') # Registered model (which contains model files/folders)
service = Model.deploy(workspace, "process-sketch-dev", [model], inference_config, deployment_config, deployment_target=aks_target, overwrite=True)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output = True)
print(service.state)
```

---